# Could not load SWT library error

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-server, ibm-installation-manager

**What I want to achieve:**

1) To install IBM Installation Manager in Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (HVM)

**What I've done:**

1) Installed "agent.installer.linux.gtk.x86_64_1.8.4000.20151125_0201.zip"

2) Run ./userinst command

**Problems:**

> ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-133:~/wkMacDownloads$ ./userinst
>
> 00:00.42 ERROR [main] com.ibm.cic.agent.internal.ui.AgentUI
>   reportStatus
>
> Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
>
> /home/ubuntu/wkMacDownloads/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/784/1/.cp/libswt-pi-gtk-4239.so
>   (libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory)
>
> swt-pi-gtk (Not found in java.library.path)
>
> /home/ubuntu/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi-gtk-4239.so
>   (/home/ubuntu/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/liblibswt-pi-gtk-4239.so.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
>
> /home/ubuntu/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi-gtk.so
>   (/home/ubuntu/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/liblibswt-pi-gtk.so.so: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory)
>
> /home/ubuntu/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi-gtk-4239.so
>   (libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory)
>
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
>
> /home/ubuntu/wkMacDownloads/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/784/1/.cp/libswt-pi-gtk-4239.so
>   (libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory)
>
> swt-pi-gtk (Not found in java.library.path)
>
> /home/ubuntu/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi-gtk-4239.so
>   (/home/ubuntu/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/liblibswt-pi-gtk-4239.so.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
>
> /home/ubuntu/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi-gtk.so
>   (/home/ubuntu/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/liblibswt-pi-gtk.so.so: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory)
>
> /home/ubuntu/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi-gtk-4239.so
>   (libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory)
>
> ```
> at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:331)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:240)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.<clinit>(OS.java:23)
>
> at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
>
> ...
> ```
>
> The displayed failed to initialize.  See the log

**Question:**

Is it possible to use IBM Installation Manager GUI mode in Ubuntu Server? Or is there a command line alternative?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `./install` instead.
To resolve your issue,
make sure the gtk libraries are installed to support the graphical user interface (GUI).[refer](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21631478)

Answer (score -1):

You could try to install IM silently.

You can run the command ./userinstc -log log_file -acceptLicense